# How is xgboost cover calculated?

Tags: r, xgboost

Could someone explain how the `Cover` column in the `xgboost` R package is calculated in the `xgb.model.dt.tree` function?

In the documentation it says that Cover *"is a metric to measure the number of observations affected by the split"*.

When you run the following code, given in the `xgboost` documentation for this function, `Cover` for node 0 of tree 0 is 1628.2500.

```
data(agaricus.train, package='xgboost')

#Both dataset are list with two items, a sparse matrix and labels
#(labels = outcome column which will be learned).
#Each column of the sparse Matrix is a feature in one hot encoding format.
train <- agaricus.train

bst <- xgboost(data = train$data, label = train$label, max.depth = 2,
               eta = 1, nthread = 2, nround = 2,objective = "binary:logistic")

#agaricus.test$data@Dimnames[[2]] represents the column names of the sparse matrix.
xgb.model.dt.tree(agaricus.train$data@Dimnames[[2]], model = bst)
```

There are 6513 observations in the train dataset, so can anyone explain why `Cover` for node 0 of tree 0 is a quarter of this number (1628.25)?

Also, `Cover` for the node 1 of tree 1 is 788.852 - how is this number calculated?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Cover is defined in `xgboost` as:

> the sum of second order gradient of training data classified to the
>   leaf, if it is square loss, this simply corresponds to the number of
>   instances in that branch. Deeper in the tree a node is, lower this
>   metric will be

https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/f5659e17d5200bd7471a2e735177a81cb8d3012b/R-package/man/xgb.plot.tree.Rd
Not particularly well documented....

In order to calculate the cover, we need to know **the predictions at that point in the tree, and the 2nd derivative with respect to the loss function**.

Lucky for us, the prediction for every data point (6513 of them) in the 0-0 node in your example is .5.  This is a global default setting whereby your first prediction at t=0 is .5.

> base_score [ default=0.5 ] the initial prediction score of all
>   instances, global bias

http://xgboost.readthedocs.org/en/latest/parameter.html

The gradient of binary logistic (which is your objective function) is p-y, where p = your prediction, and y = true label.

Thus, The **hessian** (which we need for this) is p*(1-p).   *Note: the Hessian can be determined without y, the true labels.*

So (bringing it home) :

6513 * (.5) * (1 - .5)  = 1628.25

In the second tree, the predictions at that point are no longer all .5,sp lets get the predictions after one tree

```
p = predict(bst,newdata = train$data, ntree=1)

head(p)
[1] 0.8471184 0.1544077 0.1544077 0.8471184 0.1255700 0.1544077

sum(p*(1-p))  # sum of the hessians in that node,(root node has all data)
[1] 788.8521
```

Note , for linear (squared error) regression the hessian is always one, so the cover indicates how many examples are in that leaf.

The big takeaway is that cover is defined by the hessian of the objective function. Lots of info out there in terms of getting to the gradient, and hessian of the binary logistic function.

These slides are helpful is seeing why he uses hessians as a weighting, and also explain how `xgboost` splits differently from standard trees.  https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~tqchen/pdf/BoostedTree.pdf

Comment: Fantastic explanation. Thank you

Comment: Also, I don't suppose you could shed some light on this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33654479/how-is-xgboost-quality-calculated

Comment: @dtfoster I've been playing around with that other question - haven't cracked it yet ... There is some minor weighting going on under the hood that has some minor differences from his slides