# How is xgboost quality calculated?

Tags: r, xgboost

Could someone explain how the `Quality` column in the xgboost R package is calculated in the `xgb.model.dt.tree` function?

In the documentation it says that `Quality` "is the gain related to the split in this specific node".

When you run the following code, given in the xgboost documentation for this function, `Quality` for node 0 of tree 0 is 4000.53, yet I calculate the `Gain`  as 2002.848

```
data(agaricus.train, package='xgboost')

train <- agarics.train

X = train$data
y = train$label

bst <- xgboost(data = train$data, label = train$label, max.depth = 2,
               eta = 1, nthread = 2, nround = 2,objective = "binary:logistic")

xgb.model.dt.tree(agaricus.train$data@Dimnames[[2]], model = bst)

p = rep(0.5,nrow(X))

L = which(X[,'odor=none']==0)
R = which(X[,'odor=none']==1)

pL = p[L]
pR = p[R]

yL = y[L]
yR = y[R]

GL = sum(pL-yL)
GR = sum(pR-yR)
G = sum(p-y)

HL = sum(pL*(1-pL))
HR = sum(pR*(1-pR))
H = sum(p*(1-p))

gain = 0.5 * (GL^2/HL+GR^2/HR-G^2/H)

gain
```

I understand that `Gain` is given by the following formula:

[image: gain formula]

Since we are using log loss, G is the sum of `p-y` and H is the sum of `p(1-p)` - gamma and lambda in this instance are both zero.

Can anyone identify where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, I think I've worked it out. The value for `reg_lambda` is not 0 by default as given in the documentation, but is actually 1 (from param.h)

[image]

Also, it appears that the factor of a half is not applied when calculating the gain, so the Quality column is double what you would expect. Lastly, I also don't think `gamma` (also called `min_split_loss`) is applied to this calculation either (from update_hitmaker-inl.hpp)

[image]

Instead, gamma is used to determine whether to invoke pruning, but is not reflected in the gain calculation itself, as the documentation suggests.

[image]

If you apply these changes, you do indeed get 4000.53 as the `Quality` for node 0 of tree 0, as in the original question. I'll raise this as an issue to the xgboost guys, so the documentation can be changed accordingly.

Comment: man this has been bugging me a bit.. I'm going to work through it but I 'm impressed..      You should take a look at this question since it seems like you are learning xgboost inside oout.. It's been vexing me for a while..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32950607/how-to-access-weighting-of-indiviual-decision-trees-in-xgboost

Comment: I could see that the 1/2 factor wasn't applied but shouldv'e looked at the defaults in the source code. Nice Work!

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but could you explain why `p` is a vector of 0.5, and why that is compared to Y? Is it an initial, uninformed guess for Y?