# Why is the node gain output from xgboost different from that calculated manually?

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

We can get xgboost tree structure from `trees_to_dataframe()`：

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston

data = load_boston()

X = pd.DataFrame(data.data, columns=data.feature_names)
y = pd.Series(data.target)

model = xgb.XGBRegressor(random_state=1,
                         n_estimators=1,  # 只有一棵树
                         max_depth=2,
                         learning_rate=0.1
                         )
model.fit(X, y)

tree_frame = model._Booster.trees_to_dataframe()
tree_frame
```

[image]

In which, according to the SO thread [How is xgboost quality calculated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33654479/how-is-xgboost-quality-calculated), gain should be calculated by:

[image]

However it is different from this code:

```py
def mse_obj(preds, labels):
    grad = labels-preds
    hess = np.ones_like(labels)
    return grad, hess

Gain,Hessian = mse_obj(y.mean(),y)

L = X[tree_frame['Feature'][0]] < tree_frame['Split'][0]
R = X[tree_frame['Feature'][0]] >= tree_frame['Split'][0]

GL = Gain[L].sum()
GR = Gain[R].sum()
HL = Hessian[L].sum()
HR = Hessian[R].sum()

reg_lambda = 1.0
gain = (GL**2/(HL+reg_lambda)+GR**2/(HR+reg_lambda)-(GL+GR)**2/(HL+HR+reg_lambda))
gain # 18817.811191871013


L = (X[tree_frame['Feature'][0]] < tree_frame['Split'][0])&((X[tree_frame['Feature'][1]] < tree_frame['Split'][1]))
R = (X[tree_frame['Feature'][0]] < tree_frame['Split'][0])&((X[tree_frame['Feature'][1]] >= tree_frame['Split'][1]))

GL = Gain[L].sum()
GR = Gain[R].sum()
HL = Hessian[L].sum()
HR = Hessian[R].sum()

reg_lambda = 1.0
gain = (GL**2/(HL+reg_lambda)+GR**2/(HR+reg_lambda)-(GL+GR)**2/(HL+HR+reg_lambda))
gain # 7841.627971119211


L = (X[tree_frame['Feature'][0]] > tree_frame['Split'][0])&((X[tree_frame['Feature'][2]] < tree_frame['Split'][2]))
R = (X[tree_frame['Feature'][0]] > tree_frame['Split'][0])&((X[tree_frame['Feature'][2]] >= tree_frame['Split'][2]))

GL = Gain[L].sum()
GR = Gain[R].sum()
HL = Hessian[L].sum()
HR = Hessian[R].sum()

reg_lambda = 1.0
gain = (GL**2/(HL+reg_lambda)+GR**2/(HR+reg_lambda)-(GL+GR)**2/(HL+HR+reg_lambda))
gain # 2634.409414953051
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: Please include the source of the `Gain` equation you are posting here, as well as the justification for leaving out the `1/2` coefficient and the subtraction of `γ`.

Comment: update the source in the question

Comment: Setting `reg_lambda=0` gets much closer results.  I haven't been able to find the source of the discrepancy though.  There's [this](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/750bd0ae9a1b633b4f25d6b1928d44eb08c03c25/src/tree/param.h#L274) which looks wrong, but it's not clear if/when that gets called, since there are many other instances of `CalcGain`, `CalcGainGivenWeight`, etc., and I haven't found where the final split gains get stored.

Answer (score 2):

Eventually I found out where I was wrong. The default prediction value defined by `base_score` is `0.5`, and we should use `base_score` as model's predicted value before any tree is builded when calculate the gradient for each sample.

```py
Gain,Hessian = mse_obj(model.get_params()['base_score'], y)
```

After this, everything seems ok.